# Query specific value von Enum List in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

i´ve got a question for queriing from a list. If´ve got a xaml-view, which is binding some values from a list (the values are from a DB through a rest-service). so there are some parameters like "id", "Type" or "
blood_pressure_Value". Evrybody (every 'person') has an ID and a Type, and sometimes it has a blood_pressure_Value, but only if the type is bloodplessure. now i want to view a list, with the ID, but only with "people" which has got an type bloodplessure, because there can be some other types and no bloodplessure and i dont want them in my list. that for, i´ve got a listview, in which i´m binding the type and the BP_Value f.e.:

```
    ...<viewcell x:Name="people">
                                <Label Text="ID: "/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding ID}"/>                                        
                                <Label Text="Type: "/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding Type}"/>                                    
                                <Label Text="Value: "/>
                                <Label Text="{Binding BP_Value}"/>
     </viewcell>...
```

this is where i set the itemsource:

```
        var TempList = retList.Where(p => p.VitalType != null && p.VitalType == bloodplessure ).ToList();
        PatientenWerte.ItemsSource = TempList;
```

so, as you can see, i want to have a list, where all people are listed, which has got the type bloodplessure. but it doenst work... any idea? thanks a lot

oh btw: VitalType is a type of an enum

Comment: *"it doenst work"* in what way does it not work? Please clarify the problem. For the enum, you will need a converter to turn the enum value into a string. Also note the description of the [tag:visual-studio] tag says *Use this tag if you have a specific question about Visual Studio features and functionality. DO NOT use this tag on questions regarding code which merely happened to be written in Visual Studio.*

Comment: i found a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution:

```
        var TempList = retList.Where(p => p.VitalType != null && p.VitalType == Core.Enums.eVitalType.Temperatur).ToList();
        PatientenWerte.ItemsSource = TempList;
```

Comment: That solution? The only difference seems to be using a hard-coded value instead of a variable. If `bloodplessure` contained that value there would be no problem